# Draw tool not properly drawing polygon; selects layer underneath instead

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5

I am trying to draw a rectangle around an outline of a river basin for a step in a project. I wasn't having any trouble yesterday just inserting a polygon, but now whenever I try to create the rectangle, it instead is transparent around the basin and changes the basin to the fill color of the rectangle.

I can draw a polygon when it is outside of the basin layer, but everytime it is on top it will not draw properly.

I have made all layers unselectable, so I am not sure why it is doing this. I am using ArcMap10.5.

[image]

Comment: sounds like your settings, use the N key in editing mode to select the correct layer